# How to remove unwanted substrings in a Column using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have thousands of rows in Table 1 that contains many unknown and invalid substrings. Each substring is separated by comma and the data are not case–sensitive.

Table 1(contains invalid substrings)

```
Row     COLUMN_A                
1   Beta, gamma, eta, lambda, good              
2   Alpha, beta,theta, zeta             
3   Alpha, sigma, beta, morning             
4   Delta, gamma, zeta, etc             
Etc…
```

Table 2 (contains all the valid substrings)

```
COLUMN_B                    
alpha                   
beta                    
gamma                   
theta                   
lambda
```

Compare each substring in each row in Column_ A against all the values in Column_B.

1. Delete any substrings in all rows of Table 1 that is not equal to any value in Column_B of Table 2. For example, in Row #1, “eta” and “good” will be deleted.
2. The process repeats  for all the remaining rows in Table 1 until all invalid substrings are deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @string TABLE
(
      RowID INT
    , Value NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @string (RowID, Value)
VALUES 
    (1, 'Beta, gamma, eta, lambda, good'),             
    (2, 'Alpha, beta,theta, zeta'),   
    (3, 'Alpha, sigma, beta, morning'),             
    (4, 'Delta, gamma, zeta, etc')    

DECLARE @valid_substring TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @valid_substring (Value)
VALUES ('alpha'),('beta'),('gamma'),('theta'),('lambda')

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t2.*
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              t.RowID
            , token = 
                LTRIM(SUBSTRING(
                      t.Value
                    , number + 1
                    , ABS(CHARINDEX(',', t.Value, number + 1) - number - 1)))
        FROM (
            SELECT t.RowID, Value = ',' + t.Value
            FROM @string t
        ) t
        CROSS JOIN [master].dbo.spt_values n
        WHERE [type] = 'p'
            AND number <= LEN(t.Value) - 1
            AND SUBSTRING(t.Value, number, 1) = ','
    ) t2
    JOIN @valid_substring vs ON LOWER(t2.token) = LOWER(vs.value)
)
SELECT t.RowID, Value = STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + token
            FROM cte t2
            WHERE t2.RowID = T.RowID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')             
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT RowID 
    FROM cte
) t
```

**Output:**

```
RowID       Value
----------- ---------------------
1           Beta, gamma, lambda
2           Alpha, beta, theta
3           Alpha, beta
4           gamma
```